# How are $EA$ and $AE^T$ related, where $E$ is an elementary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $E_{n\times n}$ is an elementary matrix, and $A_{n\times n}$ is any matrix, how are $EA$ and $AE^T$ related?

I understand that $EA$ is a row operation on $A$ and $AE^T$ is the same operation on the corresponding columns of $A$, but is there an equality that relates $EA$ and $AE^T$?

Comment: My feeling is that there's no "interesting and general" equality relating the results of applying a row operation resp. a column operation to $A$. However, the following things that are certainly true. $\det(EA)=\det(AE^T)$, $rank\ EA = rank\ AE^T$, $ker\ EA = ker\ A = (E^T)^{-1} ker\ A$ (the kernel is taken when acting on column vectors). But that's probably not what you're looking for.